# Getting a video from Google Photos returns an empty file

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-photos

I'm working on an application that allows the user to import videos and edit them. The applications allows the user to import local videos, or videos from Google Photos or Drive. The following code was working

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setType("video/mp4");
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

and then, on the onActivityResult method, I copy to file from Photos or Drive

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri uri = data.getData();

    try {
       File storage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
       File app_directory = new File(storage, APP_NAME);
       if (!app_directory.exists())
           app_directory.mkdirs();

       String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
       String filename = String.format("VID_%s.mp4", timestamp);

       File file = new File(app_directory, filename);

       InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

       OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

       byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
       int read;

       while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
            output.write(buffer, 0, read);

       output.flush();
       output.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Log.e(TAG, "File Not Found", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Could not save the file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e);
    }
}
```

However since the latest update of the Google Photos app I'm only getting very small file that I cannot open with any application, and sometimes for oldest videos I'm getting a FileNotFoundException

I have tried a couple of solutions, like changing the intent to request the file like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("video/mp4");
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

or getting the InputStream through a FileDescriptor

```
ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor);
```

With the same result

Comment: Which version of Google Play Services is your app referring. Make sure you have the latest version of Google Play Services (8.4) is installed in your app project.

Comment: @AniV thanks for the tip, but I have the latest version of the play services (compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0')